# How to find the sum of column of a table in frontend

Tags: php, arrays, sum, calculation

I want to calculate the sum of column on frontend and appear the sum in tfoot. Please help me out I'm new to PHP!

```
  <?php 
      if(is_array($finalArr) && count($finalArr) > 0){
      foreach($finalArr as $key => $finalAr){
  ?>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td> <?php echo $finalAr['date']; ?></td>
                    <td>$<?php echo $finalAr['deposit'] ?></td>
                    <td>$ <?php echo $finalAr['fees'] ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Total</th>
                            <th>$<?php echo 0; ?></th>
                            <th>$<?php echo 0; ?></th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
 <tbody>

  <?php  $totalFee = $totalDeposit = 0;
          if(is_array($finalArr) && count($finalArr) > 0){
          foreach($finalArr as $key => $finalAr){
            $totalFee+= $finalAr['fees'];
            $totalDeposit+= $finalAr['deposit'];
      ?>

                        <tr>
                        <td> <?php echo $finalAr['date']; ?></td>
                        <td>$<?php echo $finalAr['deposit'] ?></td>
                        <td>$ <?php echo $finalAr['fees'] ?></td>
                        </tr>
<?php }?>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                <th>$<?php echo $totalFee; ?></th>
                                <th>$<?php echo $totalDeposit; ?></th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
<?php  } ?>
```

Hope this will help.